# Vision library detector.isOperational() = false always

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-vision

My device is Samsung, SM-T561.

I am running sample for face tracker from [Official Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker)

Play service version is 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'

LogCat:

```
01-15 00:53:00.560 5022-5067/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker I/Vision: Loading library libmobile_vision_face.so
01-15 00:53:00.570 5022-5067/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker I/Vision: libmobile_vision_face.so library load status: false
```

So my doubt is regarding the issue: [Issue 98](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98)
Does this issue is still open?

Comment: From memory the bug referenced in the issue you linked to was resolved about a year ago. How much free disk space does your device have? Do the logs mention anything else related to mobile vision?

Comment: 1.8 GB remaining

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202685/detector-isoperational-always-false-on-android

Comment: No man the question is same in wordings but different situations.

Answer (score 1):

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="face" />
<activity>
...
...
</acivity>
</application>
```

The documentation says if we use any of the API's detector.isOperational(), gms will install necessary libraries.

But in some devices the manifest meta data is a must requirement for the download to happen.

Happy coding :)